# How to plot and save tableGrob objects

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gridextra

Using `ggplot2` and `gridExtra` in R, I have a `tableGrob` which I want to plot and save.

Let's say it is a small table like this one (you can try it yourself with the biult-in dataset `iris`):

```
ggsave(plot=tableGrob(head(iris[,1:3])), filename="test.png")
```

See the result:[image: Small table]

Wonderful, it works! However... lots of white space is plotted around the table, since `ggsave` defaults to `w=7, h=7` (inches), and the table does not scale up to cover that space.
I could specify `w` and `h` manually, but I have to plot *many* tables and it would be a lot of work to find all the right values.

If I try to plot a larger table:

```
ggsave(plot=tableGrob(iris), filename="test2.png")
```

...it does not fit anymore!
[image: Big table]

So, how can I **automatically** tell the plotted table to readjust based on the plot size? Or how can I tell `ggsave` to adjust the image space to the right size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tg = gridExtra::tableGrob(iris[1:40,])
h = grid::convertHeight(sum(tg$heights), "in", TRUE)
w = grid::convertWidth(sum(tg$widths), "in", TRUE)
ggplot2::ggsave("test.pdf", tg, width=w, height=h)
```

[image]

Note: the small white margin on the left is due to the rownames being right-justified, it could be removed e.g. by tweaking the padding.